# Are there uses for sodium citrate other than with cheese?

Tags: dairy-free

I bought a tub of sodium citrate to use for [this recipe](https://www.seriouseats.com/recipes/2016/11/sodium-citrate-baked-mac-and-cheese.html). It's been in the cupboard a while and I've since discovered a mild allergy to dairy which means I won't be making it again any time soon.

Are there other things you can do with sodium citrate or am I better off giving it away?

Comment: Unsure why this would be off-topic - it's a question about uses of an ingredient in food preparation

Comment: In general, questions on "the uses" are indeed off topic, because they tend to become big-list questions. We do have exceptions for rare ingredients with few uses, https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/740/can-i-ask-about-how-to-use-a-specific-ingredient-aka-culinary-uses-guidelines - it is up to the voters to decide whether a concrete question falls under that exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sodium citrate is sometimes used in "spherification", a rather unnecessary "molecular gastronomy" technique. Beyond that, it's generally used with dairy, so not much help to you. Also, if you don't have any on hand, it can be produced pretty easily by combining lemon juice and baking soda in the proper ratio. If I were you, I'd give away the tub.

Comment: Citrate buffers can be useful: https://www.aatbio.com/resources/buffer-preparations-and-recipes/citrate-buffer-ph-3-to-6-2 You'll need some citric acid too. The citric acid is great for cleaning out lime deposits, sodium citrate, note so much.

Comment: @WayfaringStranger I don't think the OP had "RNA isolation" in mind, or he wouldn't have posted on this site. ;-)